# Is unprotected sex with a pregnant woman safe (for the baby) if the male is taking (prescription) drugs that are not approved as safe in pregnancy?

Tags: drug-metabolism

Is unprotected sex with a pregnant woman safe (for the baby) if the male is taking (prescription) drugs that are not approved as safe in pregnancy?

Due to the risk of a small amount of those drugs being contained in the male's semen and being passed on to the woman.

If the answer is "it depends on the drug" then do we have any information on whether certain general categories of drugs will be safer than others or even on specific drugs?

I undertook some proir research before asking but couldn't find anything due to the difficulty of constraining a search like this to not just return information focussed on women taking drugs during pregnancy.

Comment: You might find this useful https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089062381530040X.